# Floating point exception (core dumped) in C, unsure what the error means

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int calculate(int Col, int Row);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int num;
  int Row;
  int Col;
  char *pEnd;
  num = strtol(argv[1], &pEnd, 10);
  if (num > 20) {
    return 1;
  } 
  if (num < 1) {
    return 1;
  }
   
    for( Row = num; Row > 1; Row--){
    printf("\n");
    for( Col = 1; Col < num; Col++){
      if  (Row < num) {
    int temp = num - Row - 1;
    temp = temp / 2;
    printf("  ");
    for(temp = temp; temp > 0; temp--){
      printf("   ");
        }
      }
      printf("%d   ", calculate(Col,Row));
      }
  }
  return 0;
}

int calculate(int Col, int Row)
{
  int n;
  int r;
  int n_r;
  int i;
  int out;
    for( i = (Row - 1); i > 1; i --){
    n = i * n;
  }
  for( i = (Col - 1); i > 1; i --){
    r = i * r;
  }
  for( i = (Row - Col - 2); i > 1; i --){
    n_r = i * n_r;
  } 
     
  out = n / (r * n_r) ;
  
  return out;
}
```

I'm new to coding in C and i get the error stated in the title and am unsure which part of my code is the error, additionally is someone could explain how to step through a c program that would also be useful thanks.

The code is to print out pascals triangle to a number of rows inputted by the user. It's supposed to output it in reverse order with the bottom row have 1 element.

Comment: First of all *always* check `argc` before using `argv`. Secondly learn how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes and locate where in your code they happen, and how to then examine variables and their values at the time of the crash.

Comment: Probably divide by zero.

Comment: A big hint though: Local variables in functions are by default *uninitialized* with *indeterminate* (read garbage) values.

Comment: Inside your `calculate()` function, both `r` and `n_r` are uninitialized, that means that their value is garbage/random and possibly `0`, and that means that `out = n / (r * n_r)` is a possible division by zero. And if a division by zero happens, you get a `SIGFPE` (floating point exception).

Comment: ConnorWilliams, what do you expect `for( i = (Row - 1); i > 1; i --){  n = i * n;  }` to do?  Did you want `n = 1;` before the loop?